# Couldn't send data to thingspeak via Sim 800

Tags: https, iot, gsm, tcp, sim800

I have connected the sim800L to my PC via TTL connector. Using "putty" I tried to send data to thingspeak through sim 800 GSM module by using following AT commands.

```
AT
AT+CPIN?
AT+CREG?
AT+CGATT?
AT+CIPSHUT
AT+CIPSTATUS
AT+CIPMUX=0
AT+CSTT="www"
AT+CIICR
AT+CIFSR
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","184.106.153.149","80"
     //AT+CIPSTART="TCP","api.thingspeak.com","80"
AT+CIPSEND=73
GET https://184.106.153.149/update?api_key=JMKR1***********&field1=5 
HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n
```

By end of this code the GSM module returns SEND OK But I couldn't get data on my thingspeak channel. What can I do for this? kindly, help me out.